# How to convert Time format in ruby

Tags: ruby

I  would like to convert date given in following format

```
"21.06.2015 16:38"
```

To something like this

```
"06/21/2015 04:38 PM"
```

To do so i used

```
tim = Time.new(2005,06,21,16,38)
```

But it gave me something like this which is not what i want:

```
2005-06-21 16:38:00 +0000
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't cover any attempt to find solution to the problem on its own

Comment: Time.new(2015,06,21,16,38).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")

Comment: I have solved problem with help of this useful website: http://strftimer.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by using the strftime method, in this case it would be something like this:

```
Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

You can find the complete docs here: http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime